# Doctrine Many to Many Insert

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, doctrine, many-to-many

i have some promblem. i was research and try all suggest but no one work.

and i end up with :

> `Argument 1 passed to Entity\User::addCategories() must be an instance of Entity\Category, string given,`

i have manytomany relationship, user, user_category, and category

**user**

```
<?php

namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    public $name;


    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Category", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_category")
     */
    public $categories;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->category = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    public function addCategories(Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->categories = $category;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

**category**

```
<?php

namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="category")
 */
class Category
{

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity\User", mappedBy="category")
     */
    public $user;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->user = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user = null)
    {
        $user->addCategory($this);
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
    return $this->name;
    }
}
```

**Insert function**

```
        // check existence object in database
        $res = $this->em->find('Entity\User', $this->input->post('id'));

        if($res){
            $data = $this->em->find('Entity\User', $this->input->post('id'));
        }else{
            // create a new User object
            $data = new Entity\User;                
        }


        $data->setName($this->input->post('name'));
        $data->addCategories($this->input->post('category'));


        // save the data object to the database
        $this->em->persist($data);

        $this->em->flush();
```

Everything goes fine on get but i'm so confuse for set to work.

thanks for your help.
sorry for my english.

Comment: the addCategory method is expecting a Category object, your passing a string to it instead. you haven't posted that part of your code, but the error message says it well

Comment: so how the right way to update this 3 table? or what type i must pass to `addCategory`? i tried everything and still face the error.

Comment: i update my post, would you take a look at them again.

Comment: I dont understand why your setting a category object into a variable called categories. something is not right there.

Comment: can you tell me in what line you expect thre was an error? i was tried end still give me same error but with `boolean given` and this `Call to a member function addUser() on a non-object in D:\WEBSERVER\xampp\htdocs\codetrine\application\models\Entity\category.php on line 66`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have lot of errors (pay attention to grammar):

instead of

```
public $categories;
public function __construct() {
    $this->category = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

it should be:

```
protected $categories;

public function __construct() {
    $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

instead of:

```
public $user;
public function __construct() {
    $this->user = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

use

```
protected $users;
public function __construct() {
    $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Instead of

```
public function addCategories(Category $category = null)
{
    $this->categories = $category;
}
```

it must be

```
public function addCategory(Category $category = null)
{
    $this->categories->add($category);
}
```

and

```
public function removeCategory(Category $category)
{
    $this->categories->removeElement($category) ;
}
public function setCategories($categories)
{
    $this->categories = categories;
}
```

Same logic on both sides. I don't know how CI works but Symfony will automatically find addSomething/removeSomething methods. Even if CI doesn't support that feature, you should still change your code as above.