# Doctrine2 Insert the data in the Join tables or mapping table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a scenario where employees and organizations tables are mapped in the separate table called `org_employees`.

I have no issue in adding the rows for the employees table and organization tables individually, but my question is how can i add the records for the `org_employees` table. Do i need to create a separate entity for `org_employees` table mean, if yes how the ORM relation happen. can you anyone guide me on this.

`Employee` Entity:

```
<?php
namespace Employee\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Library\Entity\BaseEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="employees")
 */ 
class Employee extends BaseEntity{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="employee_code", type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $empCode;       

    public function getEmpCode() {
        return $this->empCode;
    }

    public function setEmpCode($empCode) {
        $this->empCode = $empCode;
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return __CLASS__ . ": [id: {$this->id}, name: {$this->name}]";
    }
}
```

`Organization` Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Organization\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Library\Entity\BaseEntity;   

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="organizations")
 */
class Organization extends BaseEntity{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name; 

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return __CLASS__ . ": [id: {$this->id}, name: {$this->name}]";
    }
}
```

Comment: you are probably looking for many to many relationships: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional

Comment: nearly yes, but how can i persist the data

Comment: try to have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130572/doctrine-many-to-many-insert or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044864/symfony2-doctrine-manytomany-relation-is-not-saved-to-database

Comment: Depends on if OrgEmployees have any properties or not.  If no properties then using a Doctrine ManyToMany relation will do all the work for you.  Persistence is handled automagically.  If you need additional properties then you will need an OrgEmployeer entity with OneToMany relations to Org and Employee and persistence is handled like any other entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things.

1. Add a `ManyToMany` relationship between the `Employee` and `Organization`.
2. Add an additional entity `EmployeeOrganization(Link)` in between. It would mean:

   `Employee` - `ManyToOne` - `EmployeeOrganization(Link)` - `OneToMany` - `Organization`

This solution is also mentioned [here in the doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional):

> Why are many-to-many associations less common? Because frequently you want to associate additional attributes with an association, in which case you introduce an association class. Consequently, the direct many-to-many association disappears and is replaced by one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating classes.

The first solution is the simplest when it comes down to your entity definitions but it only allows you to do the linking and nothing more. The advantage of the second solution is that you can add additional fields to your join table (in other words properties or attributes to your entity) . For example a field `created_at` that tells you when the employee was added to the organization.

If additional properties like that are not needed you can do with `ManyToMany`.

On how to define these relationships I would like to refer to the documentation or other stack**overflow** questions, there is enough information out there.

Comment: The second solution is the necessary solution for me, because i have the scenario of extra columns in my link table.

Comment: Can you please guide me for first solution? some link of how to do it? I have to add.remove multiple rows in mapped tables

Comment: @Volatil3 Chack the docs [here for unidirectional](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional) or [here for bidirectional](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional) `ManyToMany` relationships in doctrine. If you don't manage using the docs you can leave another comment.